# Split PHPunit tests to stop out of memory error

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a business app that uses phpunit for unit testing.  The business app is growing in size and growing in unit tests.  When I run phpunit to get a code coverage report, I am running out of memory. What is a good way to generate a code coverage report with lots of unit test?

Running the below phpunit.xml, I get the following error before finishing:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1068290 bytes)
```

I am using PHP5.6 and Jenkins to run the job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
  backupStaticAttributes="false"
  bootstrap="./src/bootstrap/autoload.php"
  colors="true"
  convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
  convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
  convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
  processIsolation="false"
  stopOnFailure="false"
  syntaxCheck="false"
>
 <testsuites>
  <testsuite name="module1">
   <directory>./tests/module1</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module2</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module3</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module4</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module5/directory>
   <directory>./tests/module6</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module7</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module8</directory>
  </testsuite>
  <testsuite name="module2">
   <directory>./tests/module9</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module10</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module11</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module12</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module13</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module14</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module15</directory>
   <directory>./tests/module16</directory>
  </testsuite>
 </testsuites>

 <filter>
  <blacklist>
   <directory>./src</directory>
  </blacklist>
  <whitelist>
   <directory>./src/app/module</directory>
  </whitelist>
 </filter>

 <logging>
  <log type="coverage-html" target="build/module" title="module"
   charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"
   lowUpperBound="70" highLowerBound="90"/>
  <log type="junit" target="build/logs/module.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
 </logging>

</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 9):

well, you'll rarely need to blacklist something that isn't contained inside the whitelisted files - though that may just save you time starting the tests. Whitelist the code you are testing and then `<exclude>` the directories that don't have useful source code.

As for reducing the amount of memory used, there are a few techniques that will help - first, PHP7.1+ will use a significant amount less memory. Second, find out what tests or code are using so much memory. Test listeners like [atrapalo/phpunit-memory-and-time-usage-listener](https://github.com/atrapalo/phpunit-memory-and-time-usage-listener) can report when tests use a lot of memory that is not being cleaned up. You may also find code improvements with this.

Other PHPUnit plugins like [mybuilder/phpunit-accelerator](https://github.com/mybuilder/phpunit-accelerator) try to automatically 'unset' variables. Doing so with your own `tearDown()` functions in tests will also assist.

In the short term, if the machines you are running the tests on do have a lot of RAM still available, you can simply increase the limit:

```
<!-- phpunit.xml -->
<php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1" />
    <!-- other PHP.ini or environment variables -->
</php>
```

Finally, if your codebase is truly huge, you can split the tests and coverage reports up into separate parts, writing the coverage reports to different files that are merged using the [phpcov](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcov) tool.

Comment: Addition: Using the new XDebug code coverage whitelisting functionality, or the 'pcov' module (available in PHP v7+ & PHPunit v8+ - backports may be available for PHPunit), will avoid generating coverage for your library/vendor code (usually you only need your src/ directory, or similar). This can save a huge amount of memory - and time.